# Как извлечь объекты из массива в новый объект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Я реализовал логику, в которой функция форматированных данных извлекает все ссылки, которые имеют свойства данных по умолчанию и настраиваемые свойства, и добавляет к ним идентификатор.Также, если пользовательский объект данных совпал с объектом данных по умолчанию по идентификатору, функция удалит объект по умолчанию из свойства по умолчанию и создаст родительское свойство в пользовательском объекте из объекта данных по умолчанию.

**Но в родительском свойстве в пользовательском объекте данные по ссылкам не извлекаются и не привязываются к id.
Как я могу реализовать это в качестве примера того, что функция делает с извлечением ссылок из стандартных и пользовательских объектов данных?**

```js
const data = {
    default: [
        {
            id: "first",
            links: [{
                name: "testName1",
                number: 1
            }]
        },
        {
            id: "second",
            links: [
                {
                    name: "testName2",
                    number: 2
                },
                {
                    name: "testName2.1",
                    number: 2.1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "third",
            links: [
                {
                    name: "testName3",
                    number: 3
                },
                {
                    name: "testName3.1",
                    number: 3.1
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    custom: [
        {
            id: "first",
            links: [{
                name: "testName1",
                number: 1
            }]
        },
        {
            id: "second",
            links: [
                {
                    name: "testName2",
                    number: 2
                },
                {
                    name: "testName2.1",
                    number: 2.1
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}

function formattedData() {
    let defaultData = data.default || []
    let customData = data.custom || []
    const extractDefaultDataId = defaultData.map(el => el.id)
    const extractCustomDataId = customData.map(el => el.id)
    if (defaultData.length > 0 && customData.length > 0) {
        //  create parent object from default data object
        //  if custom data object have matched to default data object by id
        customData = customData.map((cd) => {
            const parent = defaultData
                .find(dd => dd.id === cd.id)
            return {
                ...cd,
                ...(extractDefaultDataId
                    .includes(cd.id)) && {
                    parent: {
                        ...parent,
                        scope: "defaultData"
                    }
                },
            }
        })
        // remove default object from "default" property
        // if custom data object have matched to default data object by id
        defaultData = defaultData.filter(
            dd => !extractCustomDataId.includes(dd.id)
        )
    }
    // extracting all links which default and custom data has
    // and linking them to id
    return Object.entries({ defaultData, customData })
        .map(([k, v]) => v.map(({ links, ...link }) => links
            .map(el => ({
                ...el,
                ...link,
                scope: `${k}`,
            }))))
        .flat(2)
}

console.log(formattedData())
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
[
    {
        name: "testName3",
        number: 3,
        id: "third",
        scope: "defaultData"
    },
    {
        name: "testName3.1",
        number: 3.1,
        id: "third",
        scope: "defaultData"
    },

    {
        name: "testName1",
        number: 1,
        id: "first",
        parent: {
            id: "first",
            name: "testName1",
            number: 1,
            scope: "defaultData"
        },
        scope: "customData"
    },
    {
        name: "testName2",
        number: 2,
        id: "second",
        parent: {
            id: "second",
            name: "testName2",
            number: 2,
            scope: "defaultData"
        },
        scope: "customData"
    },
    {
        name: "testName2",
        number: 2,
        id: "second",
        parent: {
            id: "second",
            name: "testName2.1",
            number: 2.1,
            scope: "defaultData"
        },
        scope: "customData"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понял разъяснение вопроса но ответ на главный вопрос рекурсией например так

```
const returnNewObject = (obj) => {
  let newObj = {}
  for(let key in obj){
    newObj[key] = obj[key]
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
      returnNewObject(obj[key])
    }
  return newObj
  }
}
```